# JavaFX Table relies on index column

Tags: java, javafx

I'm just a nooby coder but I've been experimenting with JavaFX and been playing around with demos making my own applications aswell. 
Not sure of the best way to approach this but I'm making an automatic stacked barchart maker using JavaFX which relies on data in a format like this:

Client
 - Title - Value
 - Title - Value
 - Title - Value
Client
 - Title - Value
 - Title - Value
 - Title - Value

Clients are able to be added and when I add a new title it has to apply for all clients

http://i1101.photobucket.com/albums/g435/izzypod5/chart_zps7da8c9df.png
 not enough rep to post img

I have been looking at ways to do it such as:

1. Maybe having a dynamic table which adds columns onto client which would be the x axis titles for the bar chart.
2. Having a list view of client and have it correspond to a table view of titles with values next to them
3. Some sort of maps of data being added to client after client name

   ```
       public void setClientData(ObservableList<Client> clients) {
       ArrayList<XYChart.Series> seriesList = new ArrayList<XYChart.Series>();
           for (Client client : clients){
              XYChart.Series<String, Integer> series = new XYChart.Series();
              series.setName(client.getName());
              seriesList.add(series);
           }
           for(Series series :seriesList){
               for( int i = 0; i <= twc.length - 1; i++){
                   series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(twc[i], 1000));
               }
               barChart.getData().add(series);
           }
   ```

So as you see I'm getting client values and making the series iterate through a loop and setting the name for each I will be putting the titles where the twc string array is and the values corresponding the default 1000 value.

You can assume I have a list/table of clients and titles which can be added dynamically but titles are fixed for each client however The values of the titles change for each client is what I'm trying to get at.

Any ideas on how what is the best way to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: [`StackedBarChart`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/StackedBarChart.html) is probably the best option: the Clients correspond to `Series` and the Title-Value pairs to `Data<String, Number>`. Your question is a little open ended: try to implement some code and edit the question with your attempts if you get stuck.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out its just that I don't know how to fit my table around the data model of : Client - multiple Titles - multiple Values

Comment: Use a [TreeTableView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html) for the data structure.

Comment: I did consider that but I'm pretty sure that's only when you have multiple of the index/first column I want to have multiple values for the title/value columns unless maybe I can make root nodes of client with title a child of it next to value column

Comment: No, one root node(always), but not shown in your case.  Multiple first levels (Client), each with multiple title-values.  Your data is all client-title-value, just separated into a tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement `Client` something like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Client {
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
    public final String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }
    public final void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name ;
    }

    private final Map<Title, DoubleProperty> values = new HashMap<>();

    public Client(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }


    public DoubleProperty valueProperty(Title title) {
        // In Java 8, just do
        // return values.computeIfAbsent(title, t -> new SimpleDoubleProperty());

        DoubleProperty value = values.get(title);
        if (value == null) {
            value = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
            values.put(title, value);
        }
        return value ;
    }

    public final double getValue(Title title) {
        return valueProperty(title).get();
    }

    public final void setValue(Title title, double value) {
        valueProperty(title).set(value);
    }

    public Map<Title, DoubleProperty> getValues() {
        return values ;
    }
}
```

`Title` is likely pretty trivial, you may even be able to use a `StringProperty`.

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Title {
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
    public final String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }
    public final void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name ;
    }

    public Title(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }
}
```

You could now just create observable lists of Clients and Titles, and register listeners with them to update the data for a `StackedBarChart` when items are added or removed from the lists. A more concise way, if you are using Java 8, is to use the [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) framework and just bind the contents of the series and data to maps of the data in the lists.

This example uses [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind):

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.fxmisc.easybind.EasyBind;

public class StackedBarChartExample extends Application {

    private final ObservableList<Title> titles = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final ObservableList<Client> clients = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final ObservableList<Series<String, Number>> mappedSeries = EasyBind.map(
        clients, client -> {
            Series<String, Number> series = new Series<>();
            ObservableList<Data<String, Number>> mappedData = EasyBind.map(
                titles,
                title -> {
                    Data<String, Number> data = new Data<>();
                    data.XValueProperty().bind(title.nameProperty());
                    data.YValueProperty().bind(client.valueProperty(title));
                    return data;
                });
            series.setData(mappedData);
            series.nameProperty().bind(client.nameProperty());
            return series;
        });



    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        StackedBarChart<String, Number> barChart = new StackedBarChart<>(xAxis,
                yAxis);
        barChart.setAnimated(false);

        Bindings.bindContent(barChart.getData(), mappedSeries);

        xAxis.setCategories(EasyBind.map(titles, Title::getName));

        Title awaitingResponse = new Title("Awaiting Response");
        Title agreed = new Title("Agreed");
        Title workInProgress = new Title("Work in progress");
        titles.addAll(awaitingResponse, agreed, workInProgress);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            Client client = new Client("Test " + i);
            client.setValue(awaitingResponse, i * 1000);
            client.setValue(agreed, 3000);
            client.setValue(workInProgress, (6 - i) * 1000);
            clients.add(client);
        }

        VBox controls = new VBox(5);
        final Random rng = new Random();
        Button newClientButton = new Button("Add client");
        newClientButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            Client client = new Client("Test " + (clients.size() + 1));
            for (Title title : titles) {
                client.setValue(title, rng.nextInt(5000));
            }
            clients.add(client);
        });

        HBox titleControls = new HBox(5);
        titleControls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        TextField newTitleText = new TextField();
        Button newTitleButton = new Button("Add title");
        newTitleButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            Title title = new Title(newTitleText.getText());
            for (Client client : clients) {
                client.setValue(title, rng.nextInt(5000));
            }
            titles.add(title);
        });
        titleControls.getChildren().addAll(newTitleText, newTitleButton);

        controls.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        controls.getChildren().addAll(titleControls, newClientButton);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(barChart);
        root.setBottom(controls);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Though your easybinds don't seem to be working gonna have to look into them seem like a new feature

Comment: As in the answer, EasyBind is a [third party framework](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind). You could do this without it, but it would involve much more code.

Comment: I was talking about the easybinds you used in your code example they didn't work for the mappedSeries and xaxis.setCategores parts

Comment: Seems to not like the argument given to the mapbinding u gave    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
 Title cannot be resolved to a variable
 Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

 at treetableview.StackedBarChartExample.<init>(StackedBarChartExample.java:36)
 ... 15 more

Comment: yes im using java 8 but i get syntax error on these tokens -> {

Comment: That sounds like your IDE is not recognizing the lambda expression, which is new to Java 8, so it seems like you don't have it configured to compile under Java 8. I use Eclipse, in which you need to go to project properties, then Java Compiler, and make sure you select Java 8 for compiler compliance. (You also need to make sure the Java 8 libraries are selected under "Build Path".) For other IDEs, you'll do something similar but I don't know the details.

Comment: Thanks all works now didn't have it setup properly I would vote you up but don't have the rep yet:P