# TreeTableView Dilemma

Tags: javafx

I have a data model of :
Client - Name
Map  declared in the Client object class.

Client
-Title - Value
-Title - Value
-Title - Value
Client
-Title - Value
-Title - Value
-Title - Value

As far as I'm aware the `TreeTableView` must only abide to one datatype is there a way I can make it hold both Client and a `Map` or am I forced to make `Map` part of Client?
 Would the use of  javatuples come into play?

```
public TreeTableView createContent() {

    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>();
    //treeTableView.setRoot(root);
    root.setExpanded(true);
    //final TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<>();
    ArrayList<TreeItem<String>> rootList = new ArrayList<TreeItem<String>>();
    ArrayList<TreeItem<String>> titleList = new ArrayList<TreeItem<String>>();
    ArrayList<TreeItem<String>> valueList = new ArrayList<TreeItem<String>>();
    TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<>();

        for(Client client:clients){
            rootItem = new TreeItem<>(client.getName());//.getName());
        //rootItem.setValue(client.getName());//nameProperty().getValue());
        rootList.add(rootItem);
    }  

        for(Entry<Title, DoubleProperty> map1:map.entrySet()){
            final TreeItem<Entry<Title, DoubleProperty>> mapItem = new TreeItem<>(map1);//.getKey(),map1.getValue());
            final TreeItem<String> child2Item = new TreeItem<>(map1.getKey().getName());//, map1.getValue().getValue().toString());
            final TreeItem<String> child3Item = new TreeItem<>(map1.getValue().getValue().toString());
            titleList.add(child2Item); 
            valueList.add(child3Item);
        }

        /*for(Title title:titles){
            //final TreeItem child1Item = new TreeItem<>(client.getValue(title));
            final TreeItem<String> child2Item = new TreeItem<>(title.getName());//title.getName());
        titleList.add(child2Item); 
        }*/

        for(TreeItem<String> root1:rootList){
            root.getChildren().add(root1);
            for(TreeItem<String> title1:titleList){
            root1.getChildren().add(title1);
        }
            for(TreeItem<String> value:valueList){
                root1.getChildren().add(value);
            }
        }

    // Name column
    final TreeTableColumn<Client, String> nameColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Name");
    nameColumn.setEditable(false);
    nameColumn.setMinWidth(150);
    //nameColumn.setCellValueFactory( new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<Client, String>("value") );
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(//param -> param.getValue().getValue().nameProperty());
            new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Client, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Client, String> p) {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getValue());
        }
    });

    // Data column
    TreeTableColumn<Client, String> dataColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Values");
    dataColumn.setEditable(true);
    dataColumn.setMinWidth(50);
   // dataColumn.setCellValueFactory( new MapValueFactory<>("mapvalue");
            //new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<Client, String>("name") );
    //dataColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<Client, String>("name"));
    dataColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Client, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Client, String> p) {
        return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(p.getValue().getValue().getValues().values().toString());
}
});

    final TreeTableView<Client> treeTableView = new TreeTableView(root);//rootItem);
    treeTableView.setShowRoot(false);
    treeTableView.getColumns().add( nameColumn );
    treeTableView.getColumns().add( dataColumn );
    treeTableView.setEditable(true);
    treeTableView.setColumnResizePolicy( TreeTableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY );
    treeTableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    treeTableView.setPrefSize(515, 100);
    treeTableView.setLayoutX(10);
    treeTableView.setLayoutY(10);

    return treeTableView;
}
}
```

By doing this I get values directly under each title not on the second column and I feel like I'm cheating myself making it into string I would want to make it editable in the future so it changes the actual values within the map or client

Client Object Class:

```
public class Client {
private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
public final String getName() {
    return name.get();
}
public final void setName(String name) {
    this.name.set(name);
}
public StringProperty nameProperty() {
    return name ;
}
private final Map<Title, DoubleProperty> values = new HashMap<>();

public Client(String name) {
    setName(name);
}

public DoubleProperty valueProperty(Title title) {
    // In Java 8, just do
    // return values.computeIfAbsent(title, t -> new SimpleDoubleProperty());

    DoubleProperty value = values.get(title);
    if (value == null) {
        value = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        values.put(title, value);
    }
    return value ;
}

public final double getValue(Title title) {
    return valueProperty(title).get();
}

public final void setValue(Title title, double value) {
    valueProperty(title).set(value);
}

public Map<Title, DoubleProperty> getValues() {
    return values ;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add `Title` and `Value` to the same Node ?

Comment: No I want Titles to be displayed as child under Client parent nodes and Value to be in second column lemme add some code to show what I have atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I originally suggested a table that's what your -client-title drawing looked like.  I assumed that's how you would like to display the data.  It may not be the best way.

If you are only displaying strings, then it's easy to just provide your own string in the cellValueFactory.  However, I just tried using `<XYChart.Data<String, Integer>` and it works fine with some tricks.

I didn't use a map or anything like that.  That's why I suggested a tree table since it's similar to the chart data structure.  There's no need to store it in two different places.

The problem with TreeTables are they always need TreeItems and that doesn't happen automatically.  A regular table and chart would both update automatically when the underlying data changes.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.NumberStringConverter;

public class StackedTTV extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> chartdata = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList("Wait","Agreed","Work"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            chartdata.add(new XYChart.Series<>("Test"+i, FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new XYChart.Data(xAxis.getCategories().get(0), 1000),
                    new XYChart.Data(xAxis.getCategories().get(1), 1000),
                    new XYChart.Data(xAxis.getCategories().get(2), 1000)
            )));
        }
        final StackedBarChart sbc = new StackedBarChart(xAxis, new NumberAxis(), chartdata);

        final TreeTableView<XYChart.Data<String, Number>> ttv = new TreeTableView<>(
                new TreeItem<XYChart.Data<String,Number>>(new XYChart.Data<>()));
        ttv.setShowRoot(false);

        for (XYChart.Series<String, Number> serie: chartdata){
            TreeItem<XYChart.Data<String,Number>> ti = new TreeItem<>(new XYChart.Data<>(serie.getName(), null));
            ttv.getRoot().getChildren().add(ti);
            for (XYChart.Data<String,Number> data : serie.getData()){
                ti.getChildren().add(new TreeItem(data));
            }
        }

        TreeTableColumn<XYChart.Data<String,Number>,String> clientCol = new TreeTableColumn<>("client");
        clientCol.setCellValueFactory((param) -> {
            return param.getValue().isLeaf() 
                    ? new SimpleStringProperty("")
                    : param.getValue().getValue().XValueProperty();
        });
        clientCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn());
        clientCol.setOnEditCommit((evt) ->{
            if (evt.getRowValue().isLeaf()) return;
            for (XYChart.Series serie: chartdata){
                if (serie.getName().equals(evt.getOldValue()))
                    serie.setName(evt.getNewValue());
            }
            evt.getRowValue().getValue().setXValue(evt.getNewValue());
        });

        TreeTableColumn<XYChart.Data<String,Number>,String> titleCol = new TreeTableColumn<>("title");
        titleCol.setCellValueFactory((param) -> {
            return param.getValue().isLeaf() 
                    ? param.getValue().getValue().XValueProperty()
                    : new SimpleStringProperty("");
        });
        titleCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn());
        titleCol.setOnEditCommit((evt) -> {
            final String ov = evt.getOldValue();
            final String nv = evt.getNewValue();
            //change the name for all series
            for (XYChart.Series<String, Number> serie : chartdata)
                for (XYChart.Data<String, Number> data : serie.getData())
                    if(ov.equals(data.getXValue()))  data.setXValue(nv);
            xAxis.getCategories().set(xAxis.getCategories().indexOf(ov),nv);
            //chart is confused as to which categories to listen to
            //System.out.println(sbc.getXAxis().getTickMarks());
        });

        TreeTableColumn<XYChart.Data<String,Number>,Number> valueCol = new TreeTableColumn<>("value");
        valueCol.setCellValueFactory((param) -> {
            return param.getValue().getValue().YValueProperty();
        });
        valueCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter()));
        valueCol.setOnEditCommit((evt) ->{
            evt.getRowValue().getValue().setYValue(evt.getNewValue());
        });

        ttv.getColumns().addAll(clientCol,titleCol,valueCol);
        ttv.setColumnResizePolicy(TreeTableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        ttv.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        ttv.setEditable(true);

        final TextField txt = new TextField();
        txt.setPromptText("new title");
        txt.setOnAction((evt)->{
            //add to category axis
            //todo - check for dup
            xAxis.getCategories().add(txt.getText());
            //add new title to each series with 1000 and to table
            for (XYChart.Series<String, Number> serie : chartdata) {
                XYChart.Data<String, Number> newdata = new XYChart.Data<>(txt.getText(), 1000);
                serie.getData().add(newdata);
                for(TreeItem<XYChart.Data<String,Number>> ti:  ttv.getRoot().getChildren()){
                    if(ti.getValue().XValueProperty().get().equals(serie.getName())){
                        ti.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(newdata));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        final VBox sceneRoot = new VBox(ttv,sbc,txt);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(sceneRoot);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I didnt explain myself properly I have a class Object Title which will be fixed for all clients so say there are 3 all must have them but the values are different for each client when they are set via a setvalue in Client. What I'm struggling with is retrieving the map data for each client into the treeview.                                                             Stored like this in the Client object class                       public static Map<Title, DoubleProperty> getValues() {
        return values ;  }

Comment: Added my Client Object Class so you get an idea of where I'm trying to get it from

Comment: This may still help me able to work it out myself so thanks for the effort now I know I can do it with the use of XYChart data

Comment: I know what the data is like.  I was referring to your last [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24467199/2855515) where I suggested a treetable.  I've made plenty of tables from maps but only when there is one row of data per row of table.  Every map entry will need an associated object for the table.  You'd be better off storing the client in the map with the title.  At that point you don't need a map or a tree table.  That's why I suggested using the chart data structure, which is basically already in the form you want.